# Show column even it is empty

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this SQL statement in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT "Name", "ID" FROM "NAME TABLE" WHERE "ID" IN 
(SELECT "No" FROM "LIST TABLE");
```

In the second select statement 4 "ID"s, and There is 3 "Name"s in "NAME TABLE". Currently the result is like this tale:

```
+---------------+
|Name    |  ID   |
|----------------|
|Jhon    |  23   |
|Jaas    |  25   |
|Alya    |  26   |
+----------------+
```

I want to show it as below where the fourth ID is shown without value in Name column:

```
+---------------+
|Name    |  ID   |
|----------------|
|Jhon    |  23   |
|Jaas    |  25   |
|Alya    |  26   |
|        |  28   |
+----------------+
```

Comment: do you have line in your List Table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm guessing what you want correctly... this is called an *outer join*.

First, you need to understand that your subquery with `in` is actually equivalent to the following *inner join*:

```
SELECT "Name", "ID"
FROM "NAME TABLE" n
INNER JOIN "LIST TABLE" l
ON (n."ID" = l."No");
```

Given that, you can then transform the join type to preserve non-matching rows:

```
SELECT "Name", "ID"
FROM "NAME TABLE" n
RIGHT OUTER JOIN "LIST TABLE" l
ON (n."ID" = l."No");
```

Here, "right outer join" means "For each righthand row, if there's no lefthand row that matches the join condition, keep the righthand row anyway and put nulls in place of the lefthand row".

People use left outer joins a lot more than right outer joins. They're really much the same thing - "x left outer join y" is the same as "y right outer join x" except that the display of columns is "x, y" instead of "y, x". The rows produced are the same.

To learn more, see [the PostgreSQL documentation tutorial on joins](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html).